# Pad DateTimeFormatter with traling zeros

Tags: java, datetime, padding, date-formatting, zero-pad

I'm creating an application where the user picks a date and time in a calendar which then should be shown in a text field as 26 digits, padding the date with trailing zeroes.

So the date should be displayed in the following format:

`yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS000000000`

So after millisecond (SSS) I want to fill out the string with 9 zeros. The problem is that this does not seem to be possible without adding a whitespace between the pattern letters and the zero constants.

The funny thing is that if I do `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS000000000")` I get a  `DateTimeParseException`, but the String is actually formatted as desired in the textfield. Problem is that  when surrounding the instantiation of `DateTimeFormatter` with a try-catch block, Eclipse tells me  `Unreachable catch block for DateTimeParseException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body` because the exception is thrown in some dependency class to my textfield. Moreover, it seems bad practice to catch an error that will be thrown every time the code is executed.

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS 000000000")` does compile. But I really need it to be a String without any whitespaces.

Is this possible? I'm currently using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, but if there's some class out the there extending it, I guess using it would be okay as well. Although I would prefer avoiding adding additional dependencies.

Comment: Well, I just realised that something else was giving me the exception. I did try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'000000000'")` but since the exception remained I dismissed that attempt. I'm just gonna mark @Ken Geis' as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'000000000'")`

Answer (score 1):

Use the a  [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) with the [appendPattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) method

> public DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendPattern(String pattern)
>
> Appends the elements defined by the specified pattern to the builder.
>
> All letters 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' are reserved as pattern letters. The characters '#', '{' and '}' are reserved for future use. The characters '[' and ']' indicate optional patterns.

You can use it like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
public class TimeFormatteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
        dtfb.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
        dtfb.appendPattern("000000000");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = dtfb.toFormatter();
        System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    }
}
```

The output will be in the form:

```
20151104003532968000000000
```